# Is it possible to overlay custom ImageViews?

Tags: java, android, draw, gesture, ondraw

I have an app that displays a bitmap and the user can interact with the bitmap (zoom and drag) with touch events. Is possible to implement another Imageview on the same activity OVER the original imageView bitmap that has it's own unique touch events?

For example, I have a bitmap and the user will zoom/drag it to where they want it, then when they are ready they will be able to draw a circle (and the circles can be resizeable) on the image. The circles need to be able to be resized an moved while the image in the background stays how they originally scaled it.

Here's the code implementing what I have...

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_display);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String path = getIntent().getStringExtra(ImageDisplayActivity.KEY_PATH);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    try {
        java.io.FileInputStream in = this.openFileInput(path);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), true);
        touch = (ZoomInZoomOut)findViewById(R.id.IMAGEID);
        touch = arrangeImageView(touch);
        touch.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        in.close();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button click
    shape = (DrawView)findViewById(R.id.IMAGEID2);
}
```

The XML

```
<com.commonsware.android.test1.ZoomInZoomOut
    android:id="@+id/IMAGEID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<com.commonsware.android.test1.DrawView
    android:id="@+id/IMAGEID2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="AddCircle"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do this by implementing your own ImageView by extending it. Once you have done so, you can add `GestureDetectors`, `ScaleGestureDetector`, and overriding `onTouchEvent` to implement zoom/drag and whatever else.

Then you include the two ImageViews in your Activity.

Comment: I edited my post with some code that I have. I was able to use the two image views...but I only want the DrawView imageView to activate after the user presses the button. I'm not sure why but this isn't working...